# Jconsole is complaining "file name error"

Tags: linux, alpine-linux, j

I am having trouble compiling and running J Programming Language

The Jconsole binary file (From J Language) throws an error when executed:

```
|file name error
|       0!:0 y
```

it compiled almost flawlessly but shows this warning

```
cc1: warning: function may return address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
In file included from ../../../../jsrc/j.h:1814,
                 from ../../../../jsrc/vi.c:6:
../../../../jsrc/vi.c:1202:94: note: declared here
 1202 | A jtindexofsub(J jt,I mode,A a,A w){PROLOG(0079);A h=0,hi=mtv,z;B mk=w==mark,th;fauxblockINT(zfaux,1,0);
      |
```

Comment: Your best option is to ask on the J general forum and then report the answer back here for others to see. https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Forums

Comment: I have no idea how a mailing list works. What should i do?

Comment: I think that the first step is to subscribe to the general forum. https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Forums#Subscribe When the subscription is confirmed, you will be able to send an email to that list and others will see it and reply.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Debian Linux. I ended up simply extracting the package

https://www.jsoftware.com/download/j903/install/j903_linux64.tar.gz

in `/opt` and added the line

```
alias jconsole="/opt/j903/bin/jconsole"
```

to `~/.bashrc`.